# Can you float Visual Studio 2008 Tabs?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have not been able to figure this out, but I was curious if you can float VS 2008 document tabs.  Often times, I want to look at 2 documents, maybe the aspx file and the cs file on two different screens, but I can't drag one to the other screen, so I have to just switch back and forth.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 doesn't support floating document windows, but Visual Studio 2010 <strike>will</strike> does.

Comment: You're asking why microsoft didnt think of something?  Really? heh :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create horizontal and vertical tab groups (from the Window menu).

Or, you can abandon the tabbed document approach and use MDI (Tools->Options).

Comment: Yeah, I have done that before, but I was hoping you can drag it to another screen just like they allow you to do with the properties window for example

Comment: Just tried the MDI approach, but it got kind of messy when you have many doucments and even when I did that, I could not drag a document to another screen, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to create a vertical tabbed group, de-maximise the VS window and then resize it to fill both screens, letting me have one file visible on either screen.